# Shippable Branch Coverage always 0.00%

Tags: php, phpunit, continuous-integration, shippable-ci

I am testing phpunit tests with Shippable CI but I always get 0.00% in Branch Coverage while Sequence Coverage is 100%.

This is my **shippable.yml**:

```
language: php

php: 
    - 5.4

before_script: 
    - mkdir -p shippable/testresults
    - mkdir -p shippable/codecoverage
    - mysql -e 'create database if not exists test;'

script:
  - phpunit  --log-junit shippable/testresults/junit.xml --coverage-xml shippable/codecoverage test.php
```

This is **sql.php**:

```
  class SQL {
      public static function main($bool) {
         $test = 5;
         $tmp = 0;

         if($bool + $test >= 10){
            $tmp = 10;
         }else{
            $tmp = 77;
         }

         if($tmp == 10){
            return true;
         }

         return false;
   }
 }
```

This is my **test.php**:

```
    class SQLTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        public function test() {
          $sql = new SQL();
          $doc = $sql->main(3);
          $this->assertEquals(false, $doc);
        }

        public function test2() {
          $sql = new SQL();
          $doc = $sql->main(8);
          $this->assertEquals(true, $doc);
        }

        public function testBla(){
          $test = "string";
          $this -> assertEquals($test, "string");
        }
    }
```

Do I have to do any extra configuration or is 0.00% really correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked the Shippable Support and they said:

> PHPUnit did not support branch coverage until recently, so our parser does not output branch coverage metrics for PHPUnit. 
>   From the PHPUnit docs, it does look like they might have added support for branch coverage; will open this as a feature request internally to find out if this is now in a parseable format.

https://github.com/Shippable/support/issues/1929